# Grouping up a row in SQL to show the number of distinct occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query that shows the number of clusters active for my users. For every 1 license_key, there are n-number of cluster_ids.

```
select cluster_id, license_key, created_time
    from events
where created_time >= '2018-11-04' and created_time < '2018-12-03'
    and event_name = 'cluster-ping'
group by cluster_id
order by license_key
```

This is the data:

```
cluster_id                                  license_key     created_at
___________________________________________|_______________|___________________
6D677C4196DB3C1BA84AEBC55CAEE527DDE498C7    111111111111    2018-11-26 17:17:22
CF7BF31A592030E90DAA2BADD632537FA58CD53A    222222222222    2018-11-09 16:55:38
E9A191A125C6632A87629F13E4532C7D09F6C3EE    333333333333    2018-11-24 09:49:48
B92B9F4CE642638CA71829878D27A68E4B831695    444444444444    2018-11-27 19:44:20
26BDDC912E942CC7347D26CA4D72E28E91348E41    555555555555    2018-11-11 14:10:33
F9ABEBEC93C1181635EDE2A1636D709DFD4D8E13    666666666666    2018-11-21 22:06:06
C7664728E8D0C9CAAD1ECC232DADCE00952412BC    666666666666    2018-11-20 18:04:10
FB716F791CB2C2767DB6DE74CD064E95C1A129EA    777777777777    2018-11-18 11:15:30
B5E6EF80FCBA3D3F4CFBD3E7E0477B8E5232CD05    888888888888    2018-11-18 21:08:05
1B1D17334FADBB4D739CE4A940F63E404014A05C    999999999999    2018-11-24 14:00:07
```

I have the `cluster_ids` grouped up because of the `cluster-ping` event that phones home from a cluster every 6 hours. Grouping them up ensures I only get one `cluster-ping` which indicates one active cluster, instead of all of that one cluster's `cluster-pings`, which can be numerous per cluster depending how long a cluster is alive.

I want to edit this query I know the number of times the same `license_key` shows up more than once. As you can see in the sample data above, the license key 666666666666666 shows up twice. I'd like to know in the report the number of times a `license_key` has n-number of `cluster_id`.

I have tried to use `count(license_key)` instead of `license_key`, but.. that obviously did not work.

Apologies -- new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT license_key, count(cluster_id) 
FROM (SELECT cluster_id, license_key, created_time
      FROM events
      WHERE created_time >= '2018-11-04'
      AND created_time < '2018-12-03'
      AND event_name = 'cluster-ping'
      GROUP BY cluster_id
      ORDER BY license_key ) 
GROUP BY license_key
```